# How to calculate the difference based on matching criteria

Tags: pandas

[image]

Hello,  I am trying to transfer over from excel to pandas.

I want to add new column called 'daily_volume' where if the 'project_name' is equal to the above row project_name then calculate the difference.

For example, 1,424.53 - 1,343.68 = 80.85

My goal is to see 80.85 in row 2 under the newly created 'daily_volume' column for $LONDON Gift.

Basically, the first row for a project name will always be blank.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you, the idea is to calculate the difference between the current `total_volume` and its immediately below taking into account the `project_name`, right?. You can group your dataframe by `project_name` column, select the `total_volume` and after that you can use [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html?highlight=diff#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff) method, this method make the operation you need.

1. I'm going to use the following example data:

|  | date | total_volume | project_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-08-26 | 1343.68 | \$LONDON Gift |
| 1 | 2021-08-26 | 1424.53 | \$LONDON Gift |
| 2 | 2021-08-26 | 1800.10 | \$LONDON Gift |
| 3 | 2021-08-26 | 2345.23 | \$GROUP_2 |
| 4 | 2021-08-26 | 2500.45 | \$GROUP_2 |
| 5 | 2021-08-26 | 2567.76 | \$GROUP_3 |

You can observe there are 3 different groups: `$LONDON Gift`, `$GROUP_2` and `$GROUP_3`

2. We create the new column `daily_volume` as follow:

   ```
   df['daily_volume'] = df.groupby('project_name')['total_volume'].diff()
   ```

Output:

|  | date | total_volume | project_name | daily_volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-08-26 | 1343.68 | \$LONDON Gift | NaN |
| 1 | 2021-08-26 | 1424.53 | \$LONDON Gift | 80.85 |
| 2 | 2021-08-26 | 1800.10 | \$LONDON Gift | 375.57 |
| 3 | 2021-08-26 | 2345.23 | \$GROUP_2 | NaN |
| 4 | 2021-08-26 | 2500.45 | \$GROUP_2 | 155.22 |
| 5 | 2021-08-26 | 2567.76 | \$GROUP_3 | NaN |

***A final recommendation:** Avoid to use image as data, put the code you have in the question, something like: `pd.DataFrame({...})`.*